# How to insert SharedMap into SharedObjetSequence

Tags: fluid-framework

I have the DataObject like this:

```
protected async initializingFirstTime() {
    const sequence = SharedObjectSequence.create(this.runtime);
    this.root.set("sequence", sequence.handle);
}

public async insertNode () {
    const children = await this.root.get<IFluidHandle<SharedObjectSequence<IFluidHandle<SharedMap>>>>("sequence").get();
    const map = SharedMap.create(this.runtime)
    children.insert(0, [map.handle as IFluidHandle<SharedMap>])
}
```

I definition **insertNode** method and try to insert children node when user typed some content.

But after init this data object and call **insertNode()**, I got the error: **initialMessages called twice**

[image]

I just wanner add SharedMap into SharedObjectSequence. Is any wrong for this case?

I reappear this issue by draft-js example, here are [commit code](https://github.com/qianfeiqianlan/FluidExamples/commit/143034e8899e71d43d153c0e36beb5a21d735e3b) and [insert-node-test branch](https://github.com/qianfeiqianlan/FluidExamples/tree/insert-node-test)

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a bug. There is a related issue the Fluid Framework is tracking:
https://github.com/microsoft/FluidFramework/issues/3707

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I find the root cause.

Add the **'SharedMap'** into **'SharedObjectSequence'** will receive a reply op from the server.

And will execute **'cloneDeep(message)'** in **'FluidFramework/packages/dds/sequence/src/sequence.ts'**.

The message was content **'routeContext.runtime.context.container._deltaManager.connection._details.initialMessages'**, if clone it, will call 'initialMessages' twice.

Comment: this issue was fixed in new version for fluid framework, just comment it.